# Compiling greenDAO source

Tags: greendao

When I do a fresh git clone of the greenDAO repo, import the project with Android Studio, and try to compile, references to all the Android objects throw Unresolved Symbol/Method errors. Similarly, the Android specific import statements are also unresolved.

I've gotten as far as realizing that the build.gradle files don't call `apply plugin: 'android'`, but instead lists dependencies like:

```
dependencies {
  provided 'com.google.android:android:4.1.1.4'
  provided 'com.google.android:android-test:4.1.1.4'
  provided 'com.google.android:annotations:4.1.1.4'
  provided 'com.google.android:support-v4:r7'
  provided 'com.google.android:support-v4:r7'
  ...
}
```

I've used the SDK manager to make sure I have all the files for API v4.1 installed. I also know how to use greenDAO by using the Maven repos and/or importing JARs. My problem is specific to building from source.

**Update 1**: As stated, when using `provided`, none of the Android files are found.

I don't have enough reputation to post images, but you can find a screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUbs2.png).

Comment: The dependencies are available as regular jars in Maven central: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.android%7Candroid%7C4.1.1.4%7Cjar Are you using Gradle in offline mode? What is the error out put you are getting?

Comment: Based on that comment, I changed all the `provided`s to `compile`s and everything appears to be working now. Is this the recommended best practice? Should I do a pull request to update the install instructions?

Comment: No, "provided" should work, "compile" does not make sense. Please update the question with information about the error.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I manually download all the JARs in order to use `provided`? What advantage does this have over using `compile` to have gradle pull automatically. Also, if expected to manually download the JARs, why not include them in the repo?

Comment: No, I suggested to update the question with information about the error you are getting with "provided".

Comment: I added a screenshot. Not sure what additional information I can provide. Using `provided`, no references to any android* files can be resolved.